# Periodicidad de una lista en Haskell

Tags: haskell

Necesito crear una función en Haskell, que funcione de la siguiente manera

```
periodicidad :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
periodicidad [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4...] = [1,2,3,4]
periodicidad [0,1,2,5,4,3,0,1,2,5,4...] = [0,1,2,5,4,3]
```

Es decir, que de una lista te extraiga la parte que siempre se va reptiendo, lo que en Ciencias Matemáticas se denominaría periodo de una función.

He intentado agrupar mediante `group` y `cycle`, pero no consigo nada. 
Espero que me puedan ayudar, estoy atascado y no sé qué hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener todas las sublistas desde la cabeza con la función `inits`:

```
inits [1,2,1,2]
[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,1,2]]
```

Dado que la lista vacía no nos interesa, la quitamos con la función `tail`, que devuelve la cola de la lista:

```
tail [[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,1,2]]
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,1,2]]
```

Ahora filtramos de esta lista, con la función `filter`, las listas cuyo ciclo sean iguales a la lista original:

```
filter (\x -> take (length [1,2,1,2]) (cycle x) == [1,2,1,2]) [[1],[1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,1,2]]
[[1,2],[1,2,1,2]]
```

Finalmente, cogemos la primera lista que cumpla dicha condición con la función `head`:

```
head [[1,2],[1,2,1,2]]
[1,2]
```

Juntándolo todo en una función:

```
import Data.List(inits)
period :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
period xs = head $ filter (\x -> take (length xs) (cycle x) == xs) $ tail $ inits xs
```

Por ejemplo:

```
period [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
[1,2,3]

period [1,2,1,2,1,2,1]
[1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que estamos seguros que la lista tiene un *periodo*, basta con saber cuándo la primera parte de la lista es prefijo del resto. Para esto tenemos las funciones `inits` y `tails` que nos dan todas las partes iniciales y todas las finales, por lo que bastará con comparararlas:

```
import Data.List (inits, tails, isPrefixOf)

periodo :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
periodo xs = head [ys | (ys,zs) <- tail (zip (inits xs) (tails xs))
                      , ys `isPrefixOf` zs]
```

El `tail` es para evitar el primer caso, `([],xs)`, ya que nos daría un caso falso.

Aunque así funciona en general, falla cuando no existe un periodo (eg: `[1..10]`)

Podemos dar una definición más robusta, asegurando que el periodo se repite en todo el resto de la lista:

```
import Data.List (inits, tails, isPrefixOf, cycle)
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

periodo :: Eq a => [a] -> Maybe [a]
periodo xs =
  listToMaybe
     [ys | (ys,zs) <- tail (zip (inits xs) (tails xs))
         , zs `isPrefixOf` cycle ys
         , (not.null) zs]
```